# Polymer 1.0: paper-header-panel mode issue

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am back with another Polymer 1.0 issue which seems not to be working at my end. Help!

1. I have this:

```html
<paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">
  ...
  ...
</paper-header-panel>
```

When the `mode` is set to `waterfall-tall` it is taking up too much space in the header to start with. I changed it as `model="standard"`, which  reduced the height of the header perfectly. But the problem now is the `drawer-panel` with the `menu` is not opening by clicking the collapsed menu button.

And the brand-name is not visible either with `mode="standard"`.

Try Step 2:
I kept `mode` as `waterfall-tall` and added some white space so that a vertical scroll bar appears. When I scroll down the page, the menu bar gets reduced fine, but again the collapse button stops working when I click on this.

The Drawer panel is obviously there as I can drag it from the left of the screen. But it is neither appearing on button click nor being displayed on the page so that I know there is one.

Please let me know why collapse button is not opening up the `drawer-panel` only except the mode is set to `"waterfall-tall"`

Thanks in advance,
Subrata

Comment: Post your entire code, will you? this is a problem in your code, not a general one